# PHP MongoDB Aggregation : Lookup Groupby _id

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm working in a project and I'm trying to get related documents by using the pipeline below and I don't know how I can group the results and get a unique set of items.

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "id_site": 3,
            "id_parent": null,
            "id_class": null
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categories",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "id_parent",
            "as": "Childs"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$Childs",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    }
]
```

After execute it I get this result and I don't know how I can group the results by _id and get Category 1 - Level 1 with his 2 childs inside:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5eac058490ba016d4942f782",
        "id_parent": null,
        "id_site": 3,
        "title": "Category 1 - Level 1",
        "Childs": {
            "_id": "5eac062590ba016d4942f783",
            "id_parent": "5eac058490ba016d4942f782",
            "id_site": 3,
            "title": "SubCategory 1 - Level 1",
            "Childs": null
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5eac058490ba016d4942f782",
        "id_parent": null,
        "id_site": 3,
        "title": "Category 1 - Level 1",
        "Childs": {
            "_id": "5eac324b423ea324bb762022",
            "id_parent": "5eac058490ba016d4942f782",
            "id_site": 3,
            "title": "SubCategory 2 - Level 1",
            "Childs": null
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5eac05d6684e587ee43af842",
        "id_parent": null,
        "id_site": 3,
        "title": "Category 2 - Level 1",
        "Childs": null
    },
    {
        "_id": "5eac05f50aa60f05b50faa92",
        "id_parent": null,
        "id_site": 3,
        "title": "Category 3 - Level 1",
        "Childs": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to get values for `_id` and `title`, so, you have to group on both `_id` and `title`.

Here I'm adding the further pipelines to the existing one:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "id_site": 3,
            "id_parent": null,
            "id_class": null
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categories",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "id_parent",
            "as": "Childs"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$Childs",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },
    {
      $group:{
        "_id":{
          "id":"$_id",
          "title":"$title"
        },
        "title":{
          $first:"$title"
        },
        "children":{
          $push:"$childs"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project:{
        "_id":0
      }
    }
]
```

Also, if you need a unique `child` values use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` in group stage.

For more about `$group` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

This will give you the required output.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you, Vijay. It works! I will also take a look around because after grouping the mapped class is lost. Before group the results are returned as Application\Category and after I get a MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument. ( I'm using the PHP Library)

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)